# How to start CSS3 animation when it is in view port

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, scroll

I have a bar chart that animates with CSS3 and the animation currently activates as the page loads.

Since the bar chart isn't in view when page loads, you'd have to scroll down to see it and by the time you get to it, the animation has already loaded. 
So what I am trying to do is, have the CSS3 animation activate when someone scrolls to it by using js.

Here is a sample of what I am trying to do:

[jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/pCgYe/2/)

I think I am miss something or doing something wrong in .js and .css.

```
    // Check if it's time to start the animation.
function checkAnimation() {
    var $elem = $('.skiller #skill');

    // If the animation has already been started
    if ($elem.hasClass('html5')) return;

    if (isElementInViewport($elem)) {
        // Start the animation
        $elem.addClass('html5');
    }
}
```

Thank you guys in advance!

Answer (score 1):

this is how i do it:

```
function isElementInViewport(){
            var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
            var viewportHeight = $(window).height();
            $('.skiller #skill:not(.html5)').each(function(){
                var top = $(this).offset().top;
                if(scrollTop + viewportHeight >= top ){
                    $(this).addClass('html5');
                }
            });
        }
$(isElementInViewport);
$(window).scroll(isElementInViewport);
```

Comment: thank you for your response. Do I replace my js code with the one you have?

Comment: if what you need is to add the class when the item is visible, then yes ;)

Comment: I am sorry, I am new to this :( but I pasted the js code and it didnt seem to make a difference. You can check the updated link [link](http://jsfiddle.net/pCgYe/3/) Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: thank you so much for helping me out! but the CSS3 animation is being activated as soon as the page loads still, not when when you scroll over it. Here is a working example from a different code. [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pCgYe/3/) I tried implementing that js code into mine, but I think I might be doing something wrong.

Comment: Ok, I didn't have a proper look to the HTML, the class .html5 you need to add it when you want it (not load the page with the class applied to it), please check this: http://jsfiddle.net/pCgYe/6/

Comment: YOU ARE A LIFE SAVER!! Thank you so much! One more question, what if I want to add more progress bars? Like [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/pCgYe/7/) what would I change or add in js code?